# Hex editing UI elements off an app

Tags: user-interface, hex, reverse-engineering, editing

Is it possible ot remove UI elements (buttons/images) from an application using a hex editor?
If yes any tutorial on how to do so? 
Couldn't find anything on google..
I'm trying to remove some adversting from some apps.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes this is possible, **but** you have to learn assembly and machine code (and some other things) of the targeted architecture to archive that. This is very beyond the scope of an stackoverflow answer. It's about **understanding** how a processor works internally, how data and programms are organised in your target architecture and so on...

Comment: so no easy way doing it, like searching the ui text or image in the registry and replacing it with zeros or deleting it altoghter, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way which may partially accomplish what you want is that if you know the source of the ads, you can just hex edit it to another url, or a broken url. This means that the advertisement will be gone, but the container for the ad may still be there (depending on the how the ad is configured to show)

To get the source(url) of the ads, you will need use some tools to monitor the network.

You should however, take caution, as this may be a grey area and i am not sure of the legal issues concerning this